# How to wipe and repartition dualboot and reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, reinstall, cleanup

Right now on my Dell XPS 15 I have dual boot setup with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. What's the easiest way to completely wipe everything (getting rid of any partitions) and reinstall a clean version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Backup any data from either system that you want to keep (to an external medium). Then, ignore what's on the disk, boot from a Ubuntu Install CD/USB key, and follow the instructions.

Comment: @waltinator why did  you comment instead of answer below? (honest question)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to boot from a LiveUSB, click on "Install Ubuntu", keep the default settings, and let the Ubuntu installer do all the work.

WARNING: This method will delete all existing data and partitions irrevocably. So be sure you have preserved all the data you want to keep!